# How to save the strings/integers after you use the next_permutation function?

Tags: c++

I'm totally new to c++ and while solving a problem I had to permute a number. The easiest way I found was to use the `next_permutation` function of C++. But for that I needed to convert it to a string and back to an integer number again. Problem is that, I can't store all the permuted numbers in an array after the permutation is done. It just saves the last printed number.

```
str = "131";
std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
do
{
    std::cout<<str<<endl;
    int number;
    istringstream(str)>>number;
    for(int z=0;z<3;z++)
    {
        saveInArray[z]=number;
    }

} while( std::next_permutation(str.begin(), str.end()));
```

Comment: Use a container like `std::vector<int> v` and then use `v.push_back(number);` to store the numbers. As it stands, you are overwriting four elements of `saveInArray` *every* time you create a new permutation.

Comment: What i'm noticing is that,  It prints/shows  all the permuted numbers but saves only the last integer number. Like if the number is 131, It prints 113,131,311 respectively but saves only the 311 in all the array elements. It's like this, saveInArrray[0]=311,saveInArrray[1]=311,saveInArrray[2]=311. I'm sorry for my poor English

Comment: It's not surprising you're noticing that. `for(int z=0;z<3;z++) saveInArray[z]=number;` will do that. You're saving the same number four times, every time you go through the loop. You're not saving a new number each time.

Comment: Thank you , Sir :-) , Got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is equivalent to yours, only that it uses a simple integer loop instead of `next_permutation()` to generate numbers:

```
int saveInArray[4];
// generate
for(int i=0; i!=4; ++i) {
    for(int k=0; k!=4; k++) {
        saveInArray[k] = i;
    }
}
// output
for(int k=0; k!=4; ++k) {
    std::cout << saveInArray[k] << std::endl;
}
```

Please read this code and think about what its output would be. Then, run the code and compare it to your expectations. It should show you how your code does simply not do what you intend it to and from there it should also be clear why.

Note that the suggested use of a container is due to the number of permutations, which is not at all a fixed number like `4` above!

Comment: Thank you, Sir. It was indeed a silly mistake. I still haven't still studied about containers but soon i will.

Answer (score 0):

next_permutation() can be used on any Standard Library container that has bi-directional iterators. It also appears to work on arrays according to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) which shows:

```
int myints[] = {1,2,3};
std::next_permutation(myints,myints+3)
```

So you could use a basic array instead of an STL container with bidirectional iterators (such as std::vector and std::list).

Comment: This permutes the integers in the array, while the original permuted the digits of the decimal representation of a number. This is pretty much the same, assuming you just use integers that fit into a single decimal digit. However: This does not address the problems that the question is all about!